# Upgrade Path from Globalize 1 for Rails 2.3.x Apps

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internationalization

A couple of years ago, I started using Globalize (Version 1) for my app (over 1500 translated strings and 3 locales). Since then a couple of other i18n frameworks for Rails appeared, i18n from Sven Fuchs and Globalize 2. Unfortunately, none of those are anywhere close (call) compatible with the syntax of the Globalize 1 framework.

Is there anyone out there, who has tried migrating/upgrading Globalize 1 with the latest Rails 2.3.x versions? Out of the box Globalize 1 does not work with Rails 2.3.x.  How would you go about a migration path.

Answer (score 1):

The Globalize 2 README suggests a migration script for the data:

http://gist.github.com/120867

Answer (score 0):

Go through the following URL:
http://www.botvector.net/2009/05/update-20x-to-232.html

Answer (score 0):

In the meantime I wrote [Globalize Bridge](http://github.com/chinshr/globalize_bridge) that makes the migration from Globalize 1 to 2 easier and is Rails I18n compatible. The plugin includes a rake script, which migrates strings over to an I18n Backend database.

Comment: I have fixed the link to the Git repository.